# Task Selection Problem

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

I am trying to distribute 15 tasks to two people. Each task can only be assigned to one person and each person has a time budget.

I want to express this problem as a linear program (ultimately in the standard linear form) so that I can write a computer program to solve it.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Workers& Task 1 & Task2 & Task3 & ... & Time budget \\ \hline
 Jack& 0.5& 0.25& 0.25 & & 9\\ \hline
 John&  0.75& 1.0 &0.75 & & 8\\ \hline
\end{array}

I can find plenty of examples how to do it without a budget constraint. Without it, it is an Assignment Problem that can be solved with The Hungarian Method.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : Do you think or.stackexchange.com should handle all questions with the "operations-research" tag ?

Comment: @Kuifje I merely think that the OP should be aware of the existence of OR SE. Naturally, people over there are much more enthusiastic about it than people here.

Comment: The question is tagged "linear-programming", but I think it will require integer linear programming.

Comment: If you want help have to give a reply to the comments/answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether person $i$ is assigned task $j$. Now you need a constraint that each task gets assigned to exactly one person, as well as a time budget constraint for each person.